# Routing in Codeigniter with colon in URL :

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

This route

```
$route['api2/(:any)'] = "api2/api2/$1/";
```

matches these URLs:

```
/api2/pictures/alpha_string
/api2/pictures/picture_id:alpha_string
```

but not this one:

```
/api2/pictures/picture_id:55
```

The difference is that I am using numbers after the ":".

How can I make it match the last URL?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using a colon?

Comment: why do you have two `api2` in your route.. also why not just put `$1` instead of `$1`,`$2`,`$3`.. ?

Comment: @CodeGodie: Removed the $1, $2 ... forgot them there when I was testing. api2/api2 reflects the internal structure of the site, not important for this example.

Comment: @Craig: the colon is an allowed URI character.

Comment: It's allowed in the URL, but it is not passed as a segment separator, is it?

Comment: (:any) should match any character (except "/" ?). It behaves this way when `:abc` is present in the URL but not when `:123` is

Comment: i guess the question still persists, why are you using a colon when you can use alternative characters that will do the same. Even if the colon is allowed, is it good practice to use it? I guess im wondering why is it a need to use the colon

Comment: I want to know why isn't it working. Alternatively, all those who feel inclined to, can suggest their favorite character.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use colon (:) character in codeigniter urls, you most extend **CI_Router** & **CI_URI** class from the below instructions:

First, create new file **"MY_Router.php**" in "**application/core**" folder :

```php
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_Router extends CI_Router
{
    protected function _set_request($segments = [])
    {
        parent::_set_request($segments);
        $this->_set_params($segments);
    }
    protected function _set_params($params = [])
    {
        foreach($params as $key => $value) {
            if( FALSE !== strpos($value, ':') && preg_match('/^([a-z0-9\-_]+)\:(.*)$/iu',$value,$m) ) {
                $this->uri->params[$m[1]] = $m[2];
                unset($params[$key]);
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Second, create another file "**MY_URI.php**" in "**application/core**" folder :

```php
<?php defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class MY_URI extends CI_URI
{
    public $params = [];
    
    public function param($n, $no_result = NULL)
    {
        return isset($this->params[$n]) ? $this->params[$n] : $no_result;
    }
}
function param($n, $no_result = NULL)
{
    return get_instance()->uri->param($n, $no_result);
}
```

And that's all, Now you can get separated url parameters considering the below example :

```php
$param1 = $this->uri->param('param1') // output = value1
$param2 = $this->uri->param('param2') // output = value2
$param3 = $this->uri->param('param3') // output = null
$param4 = $this->uri->param('param4', 1) // output = 1

$param1 = param('param1') // output = value1
$param2 = param('param2') // output = value2
$param3 = param('param3') // output = null
$param4 = param('param4', 1) // output = 1
```

Also, I already wrote a small library to handle using colon in urls, You can find it from this github repository : [Codeigniter Colon URI](https://github.com/alifallahrn/ci_colon_uri)